# How to test a command- and event based system with Masstransit

Tags: c#, masstransit

I have a command handler that invokes an operation on a domain object which in turn fires an event when the operation has been executed. I'd like to test that an event handler receives the event when the corresponding command has been sent (see below, some code omitted for brevity). The event handler (MyEventConsumer.Consume) is never invoked even though the event message is published on the bus (loopback bus in this case). Any ideas?

```
//Test
[TestFixture]
public class TestSendCommandReceiveEvent
{
    [Given]
    public void installation_of_infrastructure_objects()
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<MyEventConsumer>().UsingFactoryMethod(() => new MyEventConsumer(_received)));
        container.Register(
        Component.For<IServiceBus>()
        .UsingFactoryMethod(() => ServiceBusFactory.New(x => { x.ReceiveFrom("loopback://localhost/mt_client"); x.Subscribe(conf => conf.LoadFrom(container));                                                      })));
    }

    [When]
    public void sending_a_command()
    {
         var LocalBus = container.Resolve<IServiceBus>();
         LocalBus.Publish(new DoSomething(_aggregateId));
    }
    [Then]
    public void corresponding_event_should_be_received_by_consumer()
    {
        _received.WaitOne(5000).ShouldBeTrue();
    }
}
public class MyEventConsumer : Consumes<SomethingDone>.All
{
     private readonly ManualResetEvent _received;
     public MyEventConsumer(ManualResetEvent received)
     {
         _received = received;
     }
     public void Consume(SomethingDone message)
     {
         _received.Set();
     }
}

//Command handler
public class DoSomethingCommandHandler : Consumes<DoSomething>.All where T:class
{
    public void Consume(DoSomething message)
    {
       var ar = Repository.GetById<SomeAR>(message.ArId);
       ar.DoSomething();
       Repository.Save(ar, Guid.NewGuid(), null);
    }
}
//Domain object
public class SomeDomainObject : AggregateBase
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
       RaiseEvent(new SomethingDone(Id, 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work in production and just fail in a test? It appears that stuff is okay from the code, but as is I think there's some errors in the code so it's assuming that stuff connects right. I'd suggest joining the mailing list with a little more detail about what's going on. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/masstransit-discuss If I had to guess, maybe it's an issue with the container. I think we figured all of them out but it could be an outlier.

Comment: Hmm, seems to be a production issue as well. Must've configured the bus wrong. I'll have a look.

Comment: Ok, can't see what's missing here (except my own lack of experience with MT/Castle). Moving to the mailing list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This passes for me:

```
// Copyright 2012 Henrik Feldt
//  
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use 
// this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the 
// License at 
// 
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
// 
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed 
// under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR 
// CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the 
// specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

using System;
using System.Threading;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.Windsor;
using Magnum.Extensions;
using Magnum.TestFramework;
using MassTransit;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestSendCommandReceiveEvent
    {
        ManualResetEventSlim _received = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
        IWindsorContainer _container;

        [Given]
        public void installation_of_infrastructure_objects()
        {
            _container = new WindsorContainer();
            _container.Register(
                Component.For<IServiceBus>()
                    .UsingFactoryMethod(() => ServiceBusFactory.New(x =>
                        {
                            x.ReceiveFrom("loopback://localhost/mt_client");
                            x.Subscribe(conf =>
                                {
                                    conf.Consumer(() => new MyEventConsumer(_received));
                                    conf.Consumer(() => new MyCmdConsumer());
                                });
                        })));

            when();
        }

        public void when()
        {
            var localBus = _container.Resolve<IServiceBus>();
            // wait for startup
            localBus.Endpoint.InboundTransport.Receive(c1 => c2 => { }, 1.Milliseconds()); 

            localBus.Publish(new DoSomething());
        }

        [Then]
        public void corresponding_event_should_be_received_by_consumer()
        {
            _received.Wait(5000).ShouldBeTrue();
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class DoSomething
    {
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class SomethingDone
    {
    }

    public class MyEventConsumer : Consumes<SomethingDone>.All
    {
        readonly ManualResetEventSlim _received;

        public MyEventConsumer(ManualResetEventSlim received)
        {
            _received = received;
        }

        public void Consume(SomethingDone message)
        {
            _received.Set();
        }
    }

    public class MyCmdConsumer : Consumes<DoSomething>.Context
    {
        public void Consume(IConsumeContext<DoSomething> ctx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("consumed cmd");
            ctx.Bus.Publish(new SomethingDone());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, there is a short period of time, right after creation of the bus instance, during which any published messages are lost. Must be some kind of async initialization going on.

Try adding a delay between `container.Resolve<IServiceBus>()` and `LocalBus.Publish(new DoSomething(_aggregateId))`.

`Thread.Sleep` did not work in my case, but a `Console.ReadLine()` surprisingly did!

Comment: You can do: `bus.Endpoint.InboundTransport.Receive(c1 => c2 => {}, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));` instead of Thread.Sleep. The issue is that the inbound and transport receive/send loops are asynchronously initialized.